# Typed/Racket - How do I make this function work, keep getting TypeChecker errors

Tags: racket

Having

```
(: f (-> Procedure (Pairof Integer Integer) Boolean))
   (define (f comparator pair)
      (comparator (first pair) (second pair)))
```

in TypedRacket, how can I make this function work? The function is supposed to work like this:

```
(f = '(1 2)) >>>> false.
(f > '(4 2)) >>>> true.
```

I get following errors:

```
Type Checker: Polymorphic function first could not be applied to arguments
Type Checker: Polymorphic function second could not be applied to arguments
Type Checker: cannot apply a function with unknown arity
```

So probably it is the function definition which causes this error but how can I fix this?

Comment: You don’t want to use the `Procedure` type. It is not much better than `Any`, since it doesn’t specify any information about the procedure—it could take 1 argument, 2 arguments, or even no arguments! Therefore, Typed Racket won’t let you invoke it because it can’t know that you are invoking it properly. Give it a more specific type, in this case `(-> Integer Integer Boolean)`, and Typed Racket will happily continue.

Comment: Also `(Pairof Integer Integer)` doesn't refer to a list of two integers. For that you want `(List Integer Integer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a definition that does work for your examples:

```
(: f (-> (-> Integer Integer Boolean) (Listof Integer) Boolean))
(define (f comparator pair)
  (comparator (first pair) (second pair)))

(f = '(1 2))   ; => #f

(f > '(4 2))   ; => #t
```

You must define the type of the first parameter as function from two integers to a boolean, and the second argument as a list (since you used a list in the call of the function).

This is a simple definition, just to start working with types. Than you can change it to apply the function to values with more general types, like Number instead of Integer, polymorphic functions, etc.

Comment: Oh right, oh course, I had a brainlag right there, thinking in Pairs, but (first pair) is indeed a Number/Integer and not a Pairof Integer, right... My Bad right there, Thank you! Is there also a way i can make Comparator typed too? Like how Do I check if its a =, <,....

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw that (-> Integer Integer Boolean) is that comparator thing, because it takes two integers and returns a boolean.